# Do we need to pay attention to the codomain of a differentiable function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, notation, manifolds

I came across the following definitions:

> We call $M\subset \mathbb R^N$ $m$-dimensional $C^k$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^N$ if for all $a\in M$ there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $0$ in $\mathbb R^m$ and an open neighborhood $V$ of $a$ in $M$ and a $C^k$-Immersion  $\phi:U \to \mathbb R^N$ such that $\phi:U \to V$ is a homeomorphism.

Is there any good reason to state $\phi$ twice? Once with $\mathbb R^N$ as codomain and then with $V$? Can we just say that $\phi:U \to V$ is a $C^k$-Immersion and a homeomorphism?

Another example:

> Let $M$ be as in the above definition. We call $$T_aM:= \{ v\in \mathbb R^N \ | \ \ \exists \varepsilon>0 \ \ \exists \alpha\in C^1((-\varepsilon,\varepsilon),\mathbb R^N): \operatorname{im}\alpha \subset M, \alpha(0)=a, \alpha'(0)=v  \} $$ the tangent space to M at the point $a\in M$.

Can we simply write $\alpha\in C^1((-\varepsilon,\varepsilon),M)$?

Comment: I would guess that whoever defined it this way has previously defined an immersion as a map $U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ whose derivative is always injective.